# How to clear/reset videojs ControlBar on error?

Tags: video.js

I'm currently working on a React project where I'm using VideoJS with a custom design. Everything seems to be working smoothly, but I've run into an issue when the error event is triggered. The problem is that when the error event occurs, the control bar still displays the currentTime and duration from the previous video, even though I want to reset these values.

I've tried setting player.currentDuration(0) and player.duration(0) to reset these values, but this approach seems to cause issues on iOS devices. Specifically, it triggers the replay button, by adding a vjs-ended class to the player, when playing the next video after the error event occurs.

```
    player.on('error', () => {
      player.currentTime(0);
      player.duration(0);
    });
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or found a reliable way to reset currentTime and duration without causing issues on iOS devices when the error event is triggered? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!